# How can I make my vocals stand out without ducking the instrumental in my EDM drop?

Tags: production, electronic-music

I'm pretty excited about my new EDM track, but first I better figure out how to make the vocal chops in my drop stop making the instrumental sounds duck (especially the melody synth). You can really hear this at 1:08 into the song when the vocals say "Soak me in the sun". If you have ever run into this same situation and want to have a listen, what is a simple way to fix this? I'm not opposed to modifying the relative volume of the vocals and instruments at different times, but the way the volumes work together at the moment just doesn't sound right.

P.S. I have reverb and light sidechaining with the Kickstart plugin on the vocals channel. I also EQ'd out the sub and some of the bass frequencies with a high pass filter on the vocals. I work in FL Studio.

Here is a link to the unreleased song on Soundcloud: https://soundcloud.com/gideon-grossman-253590505/do-whatever-makes-you-happy/s-BhZzBG9XI4F

I have tried fixing the issue by tweaking the Fruity Parametric EQ settings on my vocal channel and various instrument channels to no avail. I have also tested modifying the Kickstart wetness on my vocal channel. Maybe there is a sweet spot I haven't hit yet or I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: It is considered bad form to cross-post the same question to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. You now have answers on both versions, so merging/migrating is no longer possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the instruments audibly duck at "Soak me in the sun".   This is what Kickstart does!  Either adjust its settings, or take the level of the vocals down a bit on that phrase.   They're obviously hitting a trigger level in Kickstart.